# "breakpoint set but not yet bound" error when debugging node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, meteor, visual-studio-code

I have configured my Visual studio code to debug nodejs, chrome(vuejs) application using the recipe in the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/meteor). I am however getting a "Failed to exec debug script" error when I debug "Meteor All" error in visual studio code. 
If I add a breakpoint in the server side code I see a "breakpoint set but not yet bound". I am however able to debug client side code correctly. 
What am I missing?

**Launch.json in visual studio code:**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Meteor: Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "outputCapture": "std"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Meteor: Node",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": ["run", "debug"],
            "outputCapture": "std",
            "port": 9229,
            "timeout": 30000
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Meteor: All",
            "configurations": ["Meteor: Node", "Meteor: Chrome"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**log in Visual Studio code:**

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd run debug 

> vue-meteor-demo@ debug c:\temp\vuemeteor2
> meteor run meteor --settings settings.json --inspect-brk=9229

Unknown run target: meteor
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue-meteor-demo@ debug: `meteor run meteor --settings settings.json --inspect-brk=9229`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-meteor-demo@ debug script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AjitGoel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-14T14_17_23_502Z-debug.log
```

**debug.log:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'debug' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predebug', 'debug', 'postdebug' ]
5 info lifecycle vue-meteor-demo@~predebug: vue-meteor-demo@
6 info lifecycle vue-meteor-demo@~debug: vue-meteor-demo@
7 verbose lifecycle vue-meteor-demo@~debug: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vue-meteor-demo@~debug: PATH: <Path>
9 verbose lifecycle vue-meteor-demo@~debug: CWD: c:\temp\vuemeteor2
10 silly lifecycle vue-meteor-demo@~debug: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'meteor run meteor --settings settings.json --inspect-brk=9229' ]
11 silly lifecycle vue-meteor-demo@~debug: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vue-meteor-demo@~debug: Failed to exec debug script
13 verbose stack Error: vue-meteor-demo@ debug: `meteor run meteor --settings settings.json --inspect-brk=9229`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid vue-meteor-demo@
15 verbose cwd c:\temp\vuemeteor2
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "debug"
18 verbose node v10.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error vue-meteor-demo@ debug: `meteor run meteor --settings settings.json --inspect-brk=9229`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vue-meteor-demo@ debug script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just use `--inspect`, and it works fine.

I have not had success specifying the port with `--inspect-brk=9229`

`--inspect` uses port 9229 anyway

Your config for the server should be like this:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "server",
  "restart": true,
  "port": 9229
},
```

The `restart` option is useful while you are editing code, as it survives server restarts (by re-attaching)

Comment: thank you @Mikkhel but changing to --inspect did not help. :(

Comment: You need to `attach` not `launch` - that would be the problem (Answer updated to show config)

Comment: I am getting an "Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change" error.  StackTrace: Started proxy. [HMR] Dev server listening on port 3003.
=> Started MongoDB. W20191120-21:06:55.498(-8)? (STDERR) Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use
=> Exited with code: 12
W20191120-21:07:04.251(-8)? (STDERR) Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use => Exited with code: 12 => Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

Comment: `9229 failed: address already in use` means that you have another process using the port already - another copy of meteor?

Comment: when I try to launch chrome and attach nodejs, I get a "this site cannot be reached" error message in the browser. If I close the browser I get the following error message: "Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229)".The application however works fine if I run npm run start command.  Please see here: https://www.loom.com/share/f95e1ab00d884d12ad13565a7ffb5a12

Comment: in the end, I was not able to debug the application using launch.json and "debug and run" options in debug. I was however able to add the --inspect option in the npm run start script as ""start": "meteor run --settings settings.json --inspect" and able to debug nodejs. Thank you @Mikkel.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this message shows up if the debugger cannot "reach" the breakpoint's file through the node process the debugger is attached to.

The error message is not well covered in VS Code documentation so it's hard to find out what causes it.

I tested this by adding a file to a project, putting a breakpoint in it but not `include`/`require`'ing it anywhere. When you run the debugger (on another file) the breakpoint you just added will be "set but not yet bound". 
Conversely, if you `include`/`require` the new file, the breakpoint will be normal (even if your tests never reach the line the breakpoint is on).

In my case, I inherited a codebase and found out that if your script spawns child processes (e.g. through [child_process.execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)), the debugger will not track the code in the child process. Instead, it will show breakpoints as "breakpoint set but not yet bound".